# Spring security client detail is going as user detail in DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

Spring Boot, Security OAuth2 implementation, default token endpoint (/oauht/token) is working fine. However, when I send a request to new endpoint at /oauth/http/token it is throws Bad Credentials because of the following reason:

`FilterChainProxy` triggers around 12 filters and out of which one is `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. It uses `UserDetailsService` of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` class to fetch user data. For client authentication this should be `ClientDetailsService` but, for some reason this is always `UserDetailsService` and because of this client credentials goes to `UserRepository` and fails. This class does initialize properly because default `/oauth/token` works fine.

I tried to inject existing Authentication Manager in `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and added that as a filter in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` but that didn’t make any difference. It does change Authentication Manager provider from `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider` to `DaoAuthenticationProvider` but `UserDetailsService` still remains `UserDetails`.

Request at `/oauth/http/token`, this doesn't work. Code is almost same as `postAccessToken()` of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint`

[image]

In above screenshot we can see that userDetailsService is UserDetailsServiceImpl and due to this client details present in request header as `Basic dGVzdDpwYXNzd29yZA==` is going to user repository and checking at user table instead of going to client repository and checking at client table.

Request at `/oauth/token`, this works

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterChainProxy` maintains not a single filter chain but a list of `SecurityFilterChain`-s.Each security filter chain contains a request matcher and a list of filters. So you will have several instances of `BasicAuthenticationFilter` in these different chains.

Which **filter chain** will be triggered depends on the incoming request and the decisions of the request matchers.

`/oauth/token` triggers the chain which is created by spring oauth and uses `ClientDetailsService` at the end.
`/oauth/http/token` triggers another chain created by your web security configuration and uses user details service.

So... that is the reason. To see how the chains are created on startup you may enable the security debug, e.g. in `application.yml`

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Then you will see the oauth security chain creation:

```
Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4ce4e309, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@16331720, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60ef29a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4c9638cc, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter@9eefda5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@16d090e9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@484a9950, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1c4fefe8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@12082780, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@20a49b7b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@24313d10, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@47ce08d2]
```

Note the request matchers.

**UPDATE:** If you want to 'remap' the endpoint to your own endpoint you may reconfigure that.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/oauth/http/token");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After checking your response, I added `http.userDetailsService(clientDetailsUserDetailsService);` and with this client table is getting searched but `BasicAuthenticationFilter` which is doing the authentication is using `PlaintextPasswordEncoder` rather than the password encoder defined in `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. I added custom `BasicAuthenticationFilter` with custom authentication manager but with this user table gets searched for client id. Is there anyway I can replicate default /oauth/token created by Spring oauth?

Comment: other than `pathMapping()`, is there any code which I can override and add few URL's that would use EXACT same filter chain that is being used by /outh/token

Comment: I'm not sure what you want or should (not) do but you are enabled to add additional filter to the oauth chain using `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer#addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter`. Filter chains are managed via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and the one for the OAuth comes from `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. All valid configurations are exposed by the authors by the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` class.

Comment: Thank you Lanchezar. I ended up using configuration similar in `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`. In `configure(HttpSecurity http)` I added custom endpoint matcher and got the same filter chain (of /oauth/token).

Comment: @VijayNandwana can you please share how you solved this?